# How to allow extension file name in route URL with react-router v5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building my CRA project, I support routes like "process.html". When I run the project with npm start, these routes work "http://localhost:3000/process.html" , but I build the project to production the route "http://example.com/process.html" don't work.

Can you help me?

React router versión:

react-router-dom: 5.0.1,

```
<Route path="/process.html" name="Process" render={Process} />
```

Comment: React has virtual DOM concept.whole project has main index.html in public folder.our all components are going to render in it.so you can create you process.js file in src folder and pass this component as route.

Comment: Yes, I have Process.js file in my src folder, but the route not work. react-router try to remove ".html" from url in build.

Comment: There is no need to pass process.html as route use only process.

Comment: I doubt this is a problem with javascript, sounds like your server isn't redirecting  requests (which aren't files) to index.html. Not enough info in question to solve.

Comment: I don't think you have process.html in your final build.our application has only index.html in build